# output operation in angular not working with event triggering

Tags: angular

this is the code...

```
sendData(inp1:Element){
    this.ele.push(inp1['value'])
    this.outData.emit(this.ele);
    console.log(this.ele);
    this.ele += inp1['value'];
    inp1['value'] = "";
}
```

console:
`[";rjg"]`

> ERROR TypeError: this.ele.push is not a function

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem, write something about what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: Do you get that error when `sendData` is called for the first time or later? What is this line supposed to do: `this.ele += inp1['value'];` ? It could convert `this.ele` to string

Answer (score 0):

If `this.ele` isn't initialized, then initialize it with empty array as `push` works with only arrays

Try this:

```
sendData(inp1:Element){
    if (typeof this.ele == 'undefined') {
       this.ele = []
    }
    this.ele.push(inp1['value'])
    this.outData.emit(this.ele);
    console.log(this.ele);
    this.ele += inp1['value'];
    inp1['value'] = "";
}
```

Comment: Please `console.log(inp1['value'])` and show the output